# How to find the resolution of these two vectors in this case?

Tags: vectors

[image]

I am getting that how did they find Angles written in Refer(b).

Like totally I am not getting which triangle they have used or drawn to find and resolve in R in the way written

Comment: You can use anyone of the two triangles formed by the diagonal and two adjacent sides of the parallelogram.

Comment: The lower triangle in the parallelogram.

Comment: How is it 180- alpha +beta @Tavish

Comment: If you see , I have draw a arc in b diagram.That should where the triangle be formed right.@AkshatSharma

Comment: @user282657 If two angles in triangle are given, the third angle can be calculated.

Comment: @user282657 Nope, the $180^o-(\alpha+\beta)$ comes from the fact that the sum of all angles of a triangle is $180^o$ and not from the straight angle.

Comment: Can you tell exactly what should I do ?

Comment: Apply the sine rule in the triangle, of course. Do you know how to?

Comment: No sir.I don’t know about it.Not Sind rule in triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Sine Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) states that for a triangle with angles $A,B,C$ opposite sides $a,b,c$ respectively, the following relation holds. $$\frac{\sin A}{a} = \frac{\sin B}{b} = \frac{\sin C}{c} $$

The triangle in your problem has two angles $\alpha,\beta$. So, the third angle is $180°-\alpha-\beta=\gamma$. The sides of the triangle are $R$ (opposite $\gamma$), $R_x$ (opposite $\beta$) and $R_y$ (opposite $\alpha$). Applying the sine rule and then taking the reciprocal gives the required relation.

Comment: Please help me in understanding that if the triangle that was given in the Wikipedia that you have shown.How did we even create sin or find sin alpha.Which is perpendicular and which one is height.I didn’t get that.

Comment: @user282657 Are you looking to understand the *proof*?

Comment: No.Just that what sides will be for sin A.Which one is perpendicular and hypotenuse.And is sin A = sin alpha

Comment: You don’t need to know the perpendicular or hypotenuse. Just do these replacements: $$A= \alpha, B= \beta, C= 180°-\alpha-\beta, a= R_y, b= R_x, c= R$$

Comment: Ok.@Tavish in that way I have got it.Really thank you.But am in doubt and confusion that why do we not take hypotenuse and perpendicular or know it’s value.

Comment: @user282657 Why do you want to know it?

Comment: It is kind of also like what I know may be not complete.I know that trigonometry angles  are solved in right angles triangles.not in this one.

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, trigonometry originates from circles. ⭕️

Comment: Sir , then how can you have a hypotenuse.

Comment: @user282657 Why can’t you? Only right angled triangles have hypotenuses.

Comment: Sir , that is what I know that only right angled triangles have hypotenuse.@Tavish

Comment: I am sorry but I did not know about it.

Comment: Is it that we can’t find the hypotenuse then but it is there ?

Comment: I don’t get what you mean. You can create a right triangle by dropping a perpendicular if you like, to get a hypotenuse,

Comment: Ok.I understood.even solved the proof .

Comment: Thank you sir. . .

Comment: and Is there any other way he could have solved it but @Tavish

Comment: No, I don’t know of any better way than this.